# Xamarin Forms: migrating to IOS Cannot set breakpoint on the specified IL offset

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to migrate my Xamarin Forms project that works pretty well on android to IOS.

When building for IOS I always get the MessageWindow popup on visual studio

```
    EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: Cannot set breakpoint on the specified IL offset. at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachine.ErrorHandler(Object sender, ErrorHandlerEventArgs args) in CMWs2017mb-043002M-1twork\144‘sWernal\debugger-libs\ Mono.Debugger.Soft\Mono.Debugger.SoftWidualMachine.cs :line 373
 at 
Mono. Debugger.Soft.Connection. SendReceive(CommandSet command set, Int32 command, PacketWriter packet) in CM\vs2017mb-00002M-1 twork\144\s \external \debugger-libs \ Mono.Debugger.SoftWono.Debugger.Soft\Connection.csain e 1805 at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.EnableEvent(EventType etype, SuspendPolicy suspend_policy, List'1 mods) in CM\vs2017mb-00002M-1 twork \144V■external \debugger-fibs\ Mono.Debugger.SoftWono.Debugger.Soft\Connedion.csain e 2682 at Mono.Debugger.Soft.EventRequest.SendReq(List'1 mods) in CM■vs2017mb-00002M-1twork \144\s \external \debugger-libs \ Mono.Debugger.SoMMono.Debugger.SoftEventRequest.cs:li ne 106 at Mono.Debugger.Soft.BreakpointEventRequest.Enable0 in CMWs2017mb-00002M-1 twork‘,144\s \external \debugger-libs \ Mono.Debugger.SoftWono.Debugger.Soft\BreakpointEventR equest.cs:line 25 at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSessioninsedBreakpoint (Breakpoint bp, Breaklnfo bi, MethodMirror method, Int32 ilOffset) in CM\vs2017mb-00002M-1 twork \144\Aexternadebugger-libs '1 Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 1197 at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolveFunction Breakpoint(BreakInfo bi, FunctionBreakpoint bp, MethodMirror method) in CM\vs2017mb-043002M-1\work\144‘s \edernal \debugger-fibs\ Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 2676 at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolveBreakpoi nts(TypeMirror type) in C:NAWs2017mb-00002M-1\work\144\Aedernal\debugger-libs\ Mono.Debugging.SoftSoftDebuggerSession.csaine 2620 at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleTypeLoad EventsffypeLoadEventa events) in CM\vs2017mb-00002M-1\_work\144\AexternaKdebugger-libs\ Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 2161 at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEventSet( EventSet es) in CMWs2017mb-00002M-1\workV144‘s \e,dernal \debugger-fibs\ Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 1690 at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandlera in CMWs2017mb-00002M-1\work \144\s \external \debugger-libs \ Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 1612
```

Any ideas what is this? I have an apple developer account, I get the app deployed to the iphone.
It just fails when I start it, I cannot debug it.

After closing the error message box, visual studio just crashes.

There is also an exception in the output window

> 2020-11-01 10:55:39.321 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[4525:348114] warning: Unable to insert breakpoint at MsFsG3000Emulator.iOS.Application:Main
> (string[]):0 Cannot set breakpoint on the specified IL offset.
>
> System.ArgumentException: Cannot set breakpoint on the specified IL
> offset.    at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachine.ErrorHandler(Object
> sender, ErrorHandlerEventArgs args) in
> C:\A\vs2017mb-00002M-1_work\144\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugger.Soft\Mono.Debugger.Soft\VirtualMachine.cs:line
> 373    at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.SendReceive(CommandSet
> command_set, Int32 command, PacketWriter packet) in
> C:\A\vs2017mb-00002M-1_work\144\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugger.Soft\Mono.Debugger.Soft\Connection.cs:line
> 1805    at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.EnableEvent(EventType etype,
> SuspendPolicy suspend_policy, List`1 mods) in C:\A\vs2017mb-00002M-1\_work\144\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugger.Soft\Mono.Debugger.Soft\Connection.cs:line 2682    at Mono.Debugger.Soft.EventRequest.SendReq(List`1 mods) in
> C:\A\vs2017mb-00002M-1_work\144\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugger.Soft\Mono.Debugger.Soft\EventRequest.cs:line
> 106    at Mono.Debugger.Soft.BreakpointEventRequest.Enable() in
> C:\A\vs2017mb-00002M-1_work\144\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugger.Soft\Mono.Debugger.Soft\BreakpointEventRequest.cs:line
> 25    at
> Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.InsertBreakpoint(Breakpoint
> bp, BreakInfo bi, MethodMirror method, Int32 ilOffset) in
> C:\A\vs2017mb-00002M-1_work\144\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line
> 1197    at
> Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolveFunctionBreakpoint(BreakInfo
> bi, FunctionBreakpoint bp, MethodMirror method) in
> C:\A\vs2017mb-00002M-1_work\144\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line
> 2676    at
> Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolveBreakpoints(TypeMirror
> type) in
> C:\A\vs2017mb-00002M-1_work\144\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line
> 2620    at
> Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleTypeLoadEvents(TypeLoadEvent[]
> events) in
> C:\A\vs2017mb-00002M-1_work\144\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line
> 2161    at
> Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEventSet(EventSet es) in
> C:\A\vs2017mb-00002M-1_work\144\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line
> 1690    at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandler() in
> C:\A\vs2017mb-00002M-1_work\144\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line
> 1612 [HotReload] (2020-11-01 10:55:37.1): WARN: StopHotReload: Could
> not find project for Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.MonoTouchDebuggerSession
> [HotReload] (2020-11-01 10:55:37.1): INFO: (MsFsG3000Emulator.iOS)
> Stopped Hot Reload session due to ExplicitlyEnded ... [HotReload]
> (2020-11-01 10:55:37.1): INFO: Stopped Hot Reload session. The app has
> been terminated.

Comment: please do not post errors as images

Comment: Are you using the latest visual-studio? If not, please update and try again.